# HashMap Getting Overwritten When Using put()

Tags: java

This is probably going to be way too much information, but just in case, I'll post everything I have:

Tester

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

enum MONTHS
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;
}
enum DAYS
{
    Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa;
}

public class MyCalendarTester {

    static MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
    static DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
        printCalendar(cal);
        menuHandler();

        System.out.println("\nI think we're done here!");
    }

    public static void  printCalendar(Calendar cal){

        GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
        dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        int formatCounter = 0;

        System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) ] + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
        }//print days of week

        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                System.out.print("   ");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
            if(formatCounter == 7){
                System.out.println();
                formatCounter = 0; //reset counter
            }
            dayCounter.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
            if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) == cal.get(Calendar.DATE)){
                System.out.print("[" + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + "]");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) <= 9){
                System.out.print(" " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
            }


        }
    }

public static void menuHandler(){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
MyCalendar mCal = new MyCalendar();
Event myEvent = new Event();    

System.out.println("\nSelect one of the following options:");
System.out.println("[L]oad [V]iew by [C]reate [G]o to [E]vent list [D]elete [Q]uit");

        char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
        switch(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice)){
            case 'L':

            case 'V': 
                     mCal.viewCalendar();
                     menuHandler();

            case 'C':
                     myEvent.createEvent();
                     menuHandler();

            case 'G':

            case 'E':

            case 'D':

            case 'Q': return;
        }


    }

}
```

MyCalendar

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyCalendar {

    GregorianCalendar calendar;
    private HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash;
    GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
    static DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();

    MyCalendar(){
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        myCalHash = new HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event>();
    }

    public HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> getMyCalHash(){
        return myCalHash;
    }

    public void setMyCalHash(HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash) {
        this.myCalHash = myCalHash;
    }

    public void viewCalendar() {

            System.out.print("[D]ay view or [M]view? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'D'){ dayView(); }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){ monthView(); }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }
    }   

        public void dayView(){
            //print day calendar
            //GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today

            System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            System.out.print("[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                dayView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                dayView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }
        public void monthView(){
            //print month calendar
            int formatCounter = 0;
            dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
            }//print days of week

            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                    System.out.print("   ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 1; i < dayCounter.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
                if(formatCounter == 7){
                    System.out.println();
                    formatCounter = 0; //reset counter
                }
                dayCounter.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
                if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) <= 9){
                    System.out.print(" " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }


            }

            System.out.print("\n[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                monthView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                monthView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }






}
```

Event

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Event {

    String eventName;
    GregorianCalendar startTime;
    GregorianCalendar endTime;

    Event(){}

    Event(String eventName, GregorianCalendar startTime, GregorianCalendar endTime){
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    } //end Event Constructor

    public void createEvent(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the event: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Date of event: ");
        String dateAsString = sc.nextLine();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
        Date date = null;
        String startTime = null;
        String endTime = null;
        MyCalendar mCal = new MyCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        String[] dateArr = dateAsString.split("/");
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]));
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

        DateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
        System.out.print("Enter starting time and ending time(24 hour format, comma separated):");
        String times = sc.nextLine();
        // checks if user entered both start and end time
        if(times.contains(",")){
            String[] time = times.split(",");
            startTime = time[0];
            endTime = time[1];

            GregorianCalendar calSTime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] sTime = startTime.split(":");
            calSTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]));
            calSTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sTime[1]));


            GregorianCalendar calETime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] eTime = endTime.split(":");
            calETime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(eTime[0]));
            calETime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(eTime[1]));
            Event myEvent = new Event(name, calSTime, calETime);

            mCal.getMyCalHash().put(calDate,  myEvent); //adding date and event to HashMap

        }else{ //if user did not specify an event end time
            startTime = times;
            endTime = null;

            GregorianCalendar calSTime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] sTime = startTime.split(":");
            calSTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]));
            calSTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sTime[1]));
            Event myEvent = new Event(name, calSTime, null);
            mCal.getMyCalHash().put(calDate,  myEvent);//adding date and event to HashMap
        }

    System.out.println("Here is what is in the HashMap:");  
    System.out.println("HashMap size = " + mCal.getMyCalHash().size());
    for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> entry : mCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()) {
        Event value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("key, " + entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + entry.getKey().get(Calendar.YEAR) + 
                " value: " + value.eventName + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
      }



    }
}
```

Every time that I call createEvent(), I am overwriting my calendar HashMap. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I want to be able to add to my existing HashMap. Please note, I do not care about conflicting events, and I can have multiple events per each date. However, right now, even when I try to add the events to a different date(key), it still overwrites the previous one.

I apologize for the obnoxiously long post, but I'm not sure how to stop it from overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mCal` is defined as a local variable inside the `createEvent()` method, so it's getting recreated every time. If you want it to live through multiple calls, you need to create it once and store it in a variable outside the method, like in a class or instance field on some other object.

Comment: Thanks, you're awesome! To expand on that (in case anyone else has a similar problem) I'm also defining mCal and myEvent locally in MenuHandler. I moved both up into the class and everything works great.